# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'hidi. users' doesn't exist

Tags: laravel

В бд вроде всё окей, таблицы правильно написаны поля тоже. Когда пытаюсь произвести регистрацию по уроку https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prl9r8nBJ5w&t=225s, выдаёт эту ошибку.
И в sql запросе откуда-то взялись пробелы перед названием таблицы и поля.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот код контроллера:

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function save(Request $request){
        if (Auth::check()){
            return redirect(route('Authentication'));
        }

        $validateFields = $request->validate([
            'Name' => 'required|string',
            'Surname' => 'string',
            'Patronymic' => 'string',
            'Login' => 'required|string|unique: users, Login',
            'Password' => 'required|confirmed',
        ]);

        $user = User::create($validateFields);
        if ($user){
            Auth::login($user);
            return redirect(route('Account'));
        }
        return redirect(route('Main'))->withErrors([
            'formError' => 'Произошла ошибка при регистрации!',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь не должно быть пробелов

```
'Login' => 'required|string|unique:users,Login',
```